# Battery drain of 20% at night without any use on nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, battery-life, 5.1-lollipop

I have recently replaced my battery on the nexus 5 . I thought I would be looking forward to a huge battery life difference but I was surprised that even with the new battery the drain is 20% at night . The phone is in wifi mode , no google now , no high brightness , greenify kills facebook app and still the battery life sucks.

Comment: I assume you have checked. But I'll ask anyway. What is the top entry on the battery usage screen? Settings > Battery.

Comment: Its the screen 10%-20% that's usual I guess

Comment: The drain at night shouldn't be the screen, assuming the phone is just sitting there idle. Maybe look into Betterbattery stats or something that can see what is keeping the phone awake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you try wakelock detector to find what is waking up the cpu and preventing your phone from deep sleeping. You might find that is it is something annoying like media scanner getting stuck and killing your battery life.

Comment: I haven't rooted my phone as yet as I don't want to lose all the data and apps . is there a app which can work without root

Comment: depending on what version of android your running wakelock detector used to work just fine even if your were not rooted that said i have not updated in months so i have no clue how well it works on none rooted devices. I rooted my devices back when the whole towel root thing was introduced so i have been rooted for a while and i have no devices that are stock to test on.